# How to avoid memory error in Python while zipping list with large number of permutations from another list to get unique combinations?

Tags: python, out-of-memory, permutation

I have the code below to generate all unique combinations between trucks and the permutations of tripares. The way I do it (below) gives me correct results. However it works only when len(tripares) < 10. When len(tripares) > 11 I get a memory error. Is there a way to avoid this memory error?

```
import itertools
from itertools import cycle

trucks=['A','B','C']
tripares = ['trip1', 'trip2', 'trip3', 'trip4', 'trip5', 'trip6', 'trip7', 'trip8', 'trip9', 'trip10', 'trip11', 'trip12'] 

# Get all permutations of the tripares list
perms = itertools.permutations(tripares,len(tripares))

# Zip the two lists and cycle the trucks list so all trips are matched with a truck
combinations = [list(zip(cycle(trucks), x)) for x in perms]

# Drop duplicates to get unique values
combs_unique = set([tuple(sorted(x)) for x in combinations ])

print(len(combs_unique))
# Should print 34650
```

Comment: what is y its not declared

Comment: What Stacktrace do you grt with the memory error?

Comment: Sorry it's len(combs_unique), not y

Comment: Just store the `zip` objects, not fully instantiated `list` objects, in `combinations`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the *number* of unique combinations you can simply compute it, without generating all those big sequences.

Let's take your example input. The first truck will have 4 (no of trips / no of trucks) of the 12 trips: it amounts to `12! / 8! / 4! = 495`. Then the second truck will have 4 of the remaining 8 trips: `8! / 4! / 4! = 70`. The third truck takes the last 4 trips: `4! / 0! / 4! = 1`. So the total count is `495 * 70 * 1 = 34650`

You may use a code like this:

```py
from math import factorial

def count_combos(n,k):
    return factorial(n)//factorial(k)//factorial(n-k)

def count_trips(ntrips, ntrucks):
    total = 1
    tt = ntrips//ntrucks
    for x in range(ntrips, tt, -tt):
        total *= count_combos(x, tt)
    return total

count_trips(12,3)
34650
```

**EDIT: get the combinations**

If you need the actual combinations, not just their number, you can generate them in your code "manually", one at a time, via recursion: list the combos for all trips for the first truck, append to each of them the list of combos for the remaining trips for the second truck, and so on until a truck has only one possible combination left. This uses a reasonable amount of memory, and also is not so slow as one may expect:

```py
from itertools import combinations

def list_combos(trips, trucks):
        #print(trips)
        combos = []
        ntrips = len(trips)
        ntrucks = len(trucks)
        tt = ntrips//ntrucks
        if ntrips == tt:
                return trips
        fs_trips = frozenset(trips)
        for c in combinations(fs_trips, tt):
                for subc in list_combos2(fs_trips.difference(c), tt):
                        #print(c, subc)
                        combos.append(c + tuple(subc))
        return combos
    
def list_combos2(fs_trips, tt):
        #print('combos2:', fs_trips)
        combos = []
        ntrips = len(fs_trips)
        if ntrips == tt:
                #print('returning')
                return (fs_trips,)
        for c in combinations(fs_trips, tt):
                for subc in list_combos2(fs_trips.difference(c), tt):
                        #print(c, subc)
                        combos.append(c + tuple(subc))
        return combos

x = list_combos(['t1','t2','t3','t4','t5','t6','t7','t8','t9','t10','t11','t12'], ['a','b','c'])
len(x)
34650
```

I tested it on 18 trips/3 trucks (17153136 combos) and also on 16/4 (63063000 combos). In the latter case it took around 275 seconds on my PC.

(Note: I'm simply returning a tuple of trips for each combo, without splitting it in `ntrucks` subtuples with the truck added. This saves some memory and speeds up things a bit; your fuel consumption calculation will simply need to consider that the first `ntrips//ntrucks` elements belong to the first truck, and so on).

**OPTIMIZATION**

Since you want to extract the best combo, why generate them all and then do the calculations? Starting from the code above it would be easy to compute the consumption of each combo once you have it, compare it with the current best and only keep track of the new best, without even maintaining the giant list.

This approach may even allow you to do some forward-check, discarding a combo *before* it is completely defined, and hence dramatically speeding up the execution.

Comment: thanks for posting. Indeed that's a very good way to get the amount of combinations but I also need the exact unique combinations since I want later on to pick the optimum comb in terms of fuel consumption

Comment: Added a possible solution to my answer

Answer (score 0):

A first try would be to use generators instead of storing the permutations immediately in a list.

```
# Zip the two lists and cycle the trucks list so all trips are matched with a truck
combinations = [list(zip(cycle(trucks), x)) for x in perms](1)

# Drop duplicates to get unique values
combs_unique = set([tuple(sorted(x)) for x in combinations ](2))(3)
```

This creates 2-3 copies of the permutations: One time by creating the combinations list.(1)
Then you create another list where you have the sorted elements(2).
And finally you use this new list, to create your list.(3)

So instead you can try to use a generator using the round brackets and immediately sort the elements in the lists:

```
combinations = (sorted(zip(cycle(trucks), x) for x in perms)
combs_unique = set(tuple(x) for x in combinations)
```

Here you really only once create the set without wasting all the space in the middle.

Comment: That won't work. The problem is in perms calculation. When the list length is 12, it crashes. I was wondering if there is a different way to get the result to avoid memory error

Comment: @Fotis Are you sure? For me this line also just creates a generator, i.e. allocates hardly any memory at all. I executed the code on my system and with 12 it takes very long but pretty much immediately reaches the combs_unique = set... expression.

Comment: I mean it takes ages to run. I still get a crash with your code. There must be a way to do it but damn I am not that good..

Comment: @Fotis maybe a different question: What actually do you want to achieve? It is quite obvious that you will get to memory issues with the permutations as with 12 you get 12! = 479001600 permutations with 8 elements in each of those permutations elements that you then have to filter through. If I didn't make a mistake that's around 10 Gb of data. But also this zipping plus sorting doesn't seem to make all too much sense to me, so maybe we can grab that problem somewhere else if you want to achieve something else.

Comment: yes of course I see your point, I struggle with it myself so I was wondering if there is a way to bypass it. What I want to achieve is get every single unique combination. Then, I can calculate fuel consumption (I have the data) for every combination and pick the combination yielding minimum fuel! So to me it seems that I can't avoid the data consuming permutations...

Comment: @Fotis I think what you are looking for then is the Traveling salesman problem. 
According to wikipedia there are some heuristics to find very good solutions even with very many cities, but I think brute forcing will not help you as you are currently doing as the number of combinations is just increasing way too quickly.